# How to hide url sub-folders?

Tags: .htaccess, url

This is my project folder:

```
*socialMedia
   -folder1
   -folder2
     - login.php
     - home.php
```

- From: "localhost/socialMedia/folder2/login.php".
- To: "localhost/socialMedia/login.php".
- This is htaccess:
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
- RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ folder2/login.php [QSA,L]

It works fine but if i want to visit the 2nd one it's not working, i can visit "**localhost/socialMedia/login.php**" but if i want to visit "**localhost/socialMedia/home.php**", its not gonna work. Do you have solution? please help me.

Comment: Well, you explicitly rewrite the requests to `.../login.php`. Of course that will not allow you to rewrite to _other_ scripts.

Comment: can you comment here the code you want me to rewrite pls? i don't understand please help me.

Comment: What is there to comment? The only rule you have (`RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ folder2/login.php [QSA,L]`) rewrites, as you can see, to `folder2/login.php`. So to your login script. The pattern that rules uses to match incoming requests (`^(.*)?$`) matches _everything_ , so every incoming request. So every request is rewritten to your login script. I suggest you start by reading the documentation of the tool you use. It is of excellent quality (as typical for OpenSource) and comes with really good examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html